# how return data from {{data.status}} to html with vue js

Tags: html, vue.js

How to conditional with Vue.js return to php.

```
{{data.status}}

<h3 v-if="data.status == 'pending'">
<span class="badge badge-warning">Pending</span>
```

Result if `data.closed` should show closed.

Comment: It's not clear, where is the issue?

Comment: As you are using Vue, hence `data.status` will contain a binded value in HTML template. You don't have to do anything explicitly to get the value. `v-if` directive will take care of that.

Comment: i want to change value with badge by colour,